# How do I hide the field in a bootstrapped DataGrid column yet keep the column width?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

When I hide a field in one of my DataGrid columns, the column's width appears to be omitted from the grid altogether, causing the sizing of all my other columns to be readjusted. Now the sizing of the column is already being auto-adjusted [responsively] by the bootstrap styling (CssClass="table table-hover"; see below). That's fine. What's not fine is the column width being adjusted a second time when I dynamically (from code-behind) hide one of the fields (Visible = false)--reason being, I have a second DataGrid identical to this first one below whose untouched column widths *must* match (I'm not hiding any fields there).

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgS" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover" ShowHeader="False" ShowFooter="False" runat="server" DataKeyField="SID" CellPadding="0" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" OnItemDataBound="dgS_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="" BackColor="steelblue" ForeColor="white" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="SID" SortExpression="SID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="   " ItemStyle-CssClass="   ">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSID" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="GradeChangeDescription" HeaderStyle-CssClass="   " ItemStyle-CssClass="   ">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlG" Runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>                          
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>   
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="C" Visible="False" HeaderStyle-CssClass="" ItemStyle-CssClass="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="lblC" Runat="server" text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "C"))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
     </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding/removing the column all together and cause resize you could hide its content with opacity. eg:
 `.fakeHidden { opacity: 0;}`

Comment: Here how I tried it:    ddlG.Style["opacity"] = "0.0";        ....it's working! Thanks.